# How do I keep track of letters guessed in a Hangman game in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have been trying to fix this program for the past two days and it is proving to be quite troublesome. It is an assignment for my intro to C++ course and has given me nothing but trouble. I have searched this board, posted on Cplusplus.com and spent hours on Google, looking for some assistance.

Here is my problem. I have been given a program and need to add a few features to it:

1. I have to save the users entries.
2. I have to display an error message if the user enters the same entry twice.

Seems simple? Not for a beginner such as myself. Here is the code, with what I have attempted to add to it in order to meet the problem's requirements.

```
int main()
{
    //declare variables
    string origWord = "";
    string letter = "";
    char dashReplaced = 'N';
    char gameOver = 'N';
    int numIncorrect = 0;
    string displayWord = "-----";
    string letterGuess[26];

    //get original word
    do //begin loop
    {
        cout << "Enter a 5-letter word in uppercase: ";
        getline(cin, origWord);
    } while (origWord.length() != 5);

    //clear the screen
    system("cls");

    //start guessing
    cout << "Guess this word: " <<
    displayWord << endl;

    while (gameOver == 'N')
    {
        cout << "Enter an uppercase letter: ";
        cin >> letter;

        //Entry Storage and Error Message. This is my problem.
        for (int x = 0; x < 26; x++)
        {
            letterGuess[x] = letter;
            for (int i = x; i < 26; i++)
            {
                if (i != x)
                {
                    if (letterGuess[x] == letterGuess[i])
                    {
                        cout << "Letter already entered. Choose another letter."
                        << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //search for the letter in the original word
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x += 1)
        {
            //if the current character matches
            //the letter, replace the corresponding
            //dash in the displayWord variable and then
            //set the dashReplaced variable to 'Y'

            if (origWord.substr(x, 1) == letter)
            {
                displayWord.replace(x, 1, letter);
                dashReplaced = 'Y';
            } //end if
        } //end for

        //if a dash was replaced, check whether the
        //displayWord variable contains any dashes

        if (dashReplaced == 'Y')
        {
            //if the displayWord variable does not
            //contain any dashes, the game is over

            if (displayWord.find("-", 0) == -1)
            {
                gameOver = 'Y';
                cout << endl << "Yes, the word is "
                << origWord << endl;
                cout << "Great guessing!" << endl;
            }
            else //otherwise, continue guessing
            {
                cout << endl << "Guess this word: "
                << displayWord << endl;
                dashReplaced = 'N';
            } //end if
        }
        else //processed when dashReplaced contains 'N'
        {
            //add 1 to the number of incorrect guesses
            numIncorrect += 1;
            //if the number of incorrect guesses is 10,
            //the game is over
            if (numIncorrect == 10)
            {
                gameOver = 'Y';
                cout << endl << "Sorry, the word is "
                << origWord << endl;
            } //end if
        } //end if
    } //end while

    system("pause");
    return 0;
} //end of main function
```

My only edit to the program is directly under the header of Entry Storage and Error Message. I have tried a single for loop, but that simply displayed the error message for every letter entered. Not only that but it displayed it 26 times. Adding a Break command fixed that and it only displayed once. However, it still displayed on every entry.

A member of Cplusplus, pointed out that I was incorrectly testing the same variable against the array in the same location. That is why it displayed the error on every entry. Now with this loop, the error only displays when an entry is entered twice. However, the error message displays all 26 times once more. On top of that, it will only error if the letters are entered one after another.

For example, if I enter A then X then A again, no error is shown. If I enter, A then A again, the error is displayed 26 times. Something is clearly wrong with how the letter variable is being entered into the array on top of the whatever is causing the error message to display multiple times.

Any amount of assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: My professor has gotten back to me and suggested using the following instead of what I have been tinkering with:

```
for (int x=0; x<5; x++)
 if (origWord[x] == letterEntered)
    origWord[x] = '-';
```

Is it just me, or does this miss the mark completely? I haven't tried converting it into my program as a simple copy and paste job produces compile errors. However, I don't see how that does anything with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: A *considerable* amount of this code disappears if you use a  [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) appropriately for managing guessed letters.

Comment: Sadly, I do not know of sets nor vectors. I have seen them used in similar programs but I do not understand them. I edited the above with some input from my professor, but it does not seem to help with anything.

Still rethinking the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

This set's all entries of your `letterGuess` array to the most recently guessed letter.

```
letterGuess[x] = letter;
```

This isn't what you want.

You need to think about the actual algorithm you need to implement:

1. The user enters a guess
2. Check to see if they've already guessed that letter
3. If they have, display an error message, return to 1.
4. If they have not, save that guess, continue with the game logic.

If you have already learned about standard containers, this can be trivially done with a `std::set`, or a `std::vector` that has been sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each element in the array to the guessed word. Best use a for loop for this. No more needs to be said if this is an assignment.

Also don't use `system("cls")` in your program, it is a massive security flaw and may lose you marks.